# Define Service Block Capacity

Tags: service, capacity

I need to implement a task that requires one specific unit of resource (A Lab Technician) which is able to process **at the same time** at most 8 agents. I want to use the Service block but I can't understand how to set the capacity of this block, that is of course different from the option queue capacity available in the parameters set.

I've tried so far with the method set_capacity() but it's not working.